# opening of the custom dialog on the click of list view

Tags: java, android

How do I open the Custom dialog on clicking the List Item of base adapter?

I tried using the code for opening the Custom dialog  by clicking on the item list ,but getting the error of windowmanager something

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {

            int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(position);
            int tempID = childPosition;
            Log.i("tempID",""+tempID);
            Log.i("Item Clicked","Position"+position);


            //Log.i("Item Clicked","Position"+position);    

            type_dilog = new Dialog(Contacts.this);
            type_dilog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogg);

            type_dilog.setTitle(" Select the Operation ");
            Log.i("3333333333","333333333");
            TextView alert_messagee = (TextView) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.dilog_messagee);
            alert_messagee.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageBtn = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.automessage_btn);
            videoBtn = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.ownmessage_btn);
            captuerimageBtn = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.captureimage_btn);
            takevideoBtn = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.takevideo_btn);
            delete = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
//              delete_no = (Button) type_dilog.findViewById(R.id.delete_no_btn);
            Log.i("44444444","4444444444");
            imageBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            videoBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            captuerimageBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            takevideoBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            delete.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imageBtn.setText("Photo Library");
            videoBtn.setText("Video Library");
            captuerimageBtn.setText("Take Picture");
            takevideoBtn.setText("Take Video");


            type_dilog.show();

}





02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41d9af60 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:683)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at dev.zoemultiline.Contacts$ContactsAdapter$1.onClick(Contacts.java:311)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
02-25 17:09:55.040: E/AndroidRuntime(27697):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Above is the Log cat error coming on the click of onItemClick when want to opening the Custom dialog

I write   type_dilog = new Dialog(getParent()); instead of type_dilog = new Dialog(Contacts.this); and it solves my problem

Answer (score -1):

Implement onitemselectedlistener for better results for your problem.

Comment: and how it will resolve his problem ? did he mention that he is using Spinner?

Comment: i am using the base adapter ,onitemclick ,i able to get the values or position but not able to open the dialog

Comment: onitemselectedlistener  is not helpful for me ,i am getting the list of all the contacts which are in the device

Comment: i had tried everything to show the details on custom dialo,but could not able to do it ,please help me for doing this

Comment: i write  type_dilog = new Dialog(getparent()); instead of  type_dilog = new Dialog(Contacts.this); and it solves the problem